# How to use windows phone as a webcam in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, webcam, windows-phone

I want to use windows phone rear camera as a webcam for my opencv app in Ubuntu. Is their any app or method?

Answer (score 0):

The only method is to use Skype.  It is available on both Windows Phone and Ubuntu.  You'll just need 2 accounts.  But, you won't be able to use the video output of Skype directly without some trickery.

To use the Windows Phone as a true webcam is not possible.  Windows Phones don't expose their hardware through USB and it's only possible to use them as storage if they're rooted.

Answer (score 0):

How about using the software of the ["Win IP Camera" for Windowsphone](https://www.microsoft.com/ja-jp/p/win-ip-camera/9nblgggz4xb1?activetab=pivot:overviewtab)?

Turn a Windows Phone device into a TRUE IP camera (i.e. network camera) instantly.
Win IP Camera instantly makes a Window Phone device into a high end HD IP camera with battery power, WiFi, flashlight, both internal and external storage, and dual-lens (for dual camera models). With Win IP Camera, your unused Windows Phone devices become high quality surveillance cameras. You can also use your Windows Phone to broadcast video to the world with your strictly controlled authorization.
Please note: WiFi connection is required.
You can use any MJPEG supporting browser (e.g. Firefox) or app (e.g. IP CENTCOM for Windows Phone, Onvifer for Android, VLC, etc.) to view the video. It currently supports only MJPEG streaming, but we plan to have full RTSP support.

Main Features:
<sub>HD Video (720p, or 1080p)

Support both landscape and portrait orientations

MJPEG with low latency

User management with privilege levels

Switching between two cameras (for dual-camera models)

Multiple resolution-selection

Snapshot

Configurable Port

Audio alarm

Even triggered snapshot capturing and siren play

Turn on/off streaming remotely (Pro)

Turn on/off flashlight remotely (Pro)

Switching camera remotely (Pro)

Terminate connections remotely (Pro)

Access log (Pro)

Unlimited concurrent connections (Pro) (Max 2 concurrent connections for the free version)

Unlimited users (Pro) (Max 2 users for the free version)</sub>